# Convert string to tuple, hash, or array

Tags: arrays, ruby, hash

I have a string:

```
"(\"Doe, John\",12345)"
```

I want to convert this string into a tuple `("Doe, John",12345)`, a hash `{"Doe, John" => 12345}`, or an array `["Doe, John",12345]`.

I'm not sure how to split it into 2 elements `"Doe, John"` and `12345`. I'd like to avoid using `regex`. I cannot use `split` because then I get `["(\"Doe", "John", "12345)"]`.

Comment: Where is the hash coming from? User input? Piped data?

Comment: it is a `PG::Result`, so there are many hashes of this type being returned in the result.

Comment: You should strike `("Doe, John",12345)` as it is not a Ruby object.

Comment: What do you mean by a tuple? You do not mean an array because you wrote "a tuple ... or ... an array".

Comment: If you're getting a "PG::Result", perhaps you should use an ORM, like [Sequel](http://sequel.jeremyevans.net/rdoc/files/README_rdoc.html), to access your database, which will take care of this sort of thing automatically. Your future self will thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Hash[*s[1..-2].gsub('"', '').reverse.sub(',', '|').reverse.split('|')]
```

Result

```
{"Doe, John"=>"12345"}
```

Explain:

```
s                                 # (\"Doe, John\",12345)
s[1..-2]                          # remove bracket => \"Doe, John\",12345
.gsub('"', '')                    # remove double quote => Doe, John,12345
.reverse.sub(',', '|').reverse    # make the last , into | => Doe, John|12345
.split('|')                       # split the string to array => ["Doe, John", "12345"]
Hash[*s]                          # make the array into hash => {"Doe, John"=>"12345"}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `scan` in cases like this, not `split`.

```
"(\"Doe, John\",12345)"[1...-1]
.scan(/(?<=")[^"]*(?=")|[^,"]+/)
# => ["Doe, John", "12345"]
```